# Is there a way to support mobile checkout using PayPal Standard?

Tags: paypal

Currently we use PayPal Standard instead of PayPal Express. Whenever we checkout using our PayPal Standard on a mobile device, the interface isn't responsive and remains in the desktop mode.

I've been doing a considerable amount of Googling around, and it seems that **PayPal Standard doesn't support** mobile version, but PayPal Express does.

It really the case? It seems a little silly how PayPal Standard doesn't detect mobile devices. Although it is a simple parameter switch to use PayPal Express, we've done a lot of work around PayPal Standard, and would *ideally* like to stick with PayPal Standard because of this work.

Comment: I think [Mobile Express Checkout (MEC)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/) and [Mobile PayPal Payments Standard (MPPS)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/) are supported to implement. But MPPS has some [unsupported use case](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/#usecases).

Comment: Thank you! It does seem to be the case. I disabled the discount fields and the mobile version kicks in for MPPS. However the discount fields are essential to us, so I suppose we'll have to switch to MEC.